# Selector not working in Textview for changing textColor for disabled state

Tags: android-layout

I want textColor as black even if textView is disabled. For it I use a selector but its not working, its giving me default grey textcolor in disabled state.
Selector file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:state_focused="true" android:color="@color/black" />
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:state_focused="false" android:color="@color/black" />
    <item android:state_enabled="true" android:state_focused="true" android:color="@color/black"/>
    <item android:state_enabled="true" android:state_focused="false" android:color="@color/black"/>
    <item android:color="@color/black"/>
</selector>
```

TextView in which selector is set is as follows:

```
  <com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialTextView
         android:id="@+id/policyEndDateText"
         style="?android:attr/spinnerStyle"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
         android:textColor="@color/textview_color_selector"
         android:enabled="false"
         android:hint="New Policy End Date"
         android:textSize="@dimen/insurance_text_size"
        app:met_floatingLabelTextSize="@dimen/insurance_floating_label_textSize"
          app:met_hideUnderline="true"
          app:met_floatingLabel="highlight"
          app:met_primaryColor="@color/material_text"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/colorPrimary_purple"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/colorAccent_purple" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/colorAccent" android:state_focused="true"/>
</selector>
```